# Switching 'views' with a cookie

Tags: cookies

On a site I'm working on, I've got a lists of projects. These lists have two views: a thumbnail and a text-list view. On each page, there's a button to switch to the other view.

I'd like to make that selection persistent. So hit the button to change views, and all pages load that view (until you change the view again).

Is there an easy/recommended way to do this?

Edit: would be nice if it were compatible with some sort of template caching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes do it by setting cookie and then checking for the presence/value of the cookie and use the result to decide which layout to show (perhaps by using a conditional to use a particular embedded template).

As ever there are add-ons to help with getting and setting cookies, take a look at [Cookies Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cookie-plus) as a starting point.

Comment: I set up Cookies Plus after I'd posted this question - I can get it to _read_ a cookie. But I can't figure out how to get cookies plus to write a cookie by using a button - i.e. press button, set cookie, reload page with new view.

Comment: From memory when I've done this I create a tiny template that has the Cookie Plus cookie setting tag and some kind of redirect (e.g. back to where the user came from). So when the button is clicked it sends the user to that template, sets the cookie and goes back to where they were. Maybe even use Ajax (not sure if you can set a cookie that way though).

Comment: Ah. In my initial build, I had the cookie set by a different page, but I felt that was a weird behavior and that I was 'doing it wrong.' I've got it working now, more or less. I grabbed a jquery script that writes a cookie on my button click (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) - a little clunky, but it's functional. Not in love with this solution, so I may regroup and try a different tack with Stash.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie Plus is fine, but if you happen to already be using Stash, it can handle this kind of thing using `save="yes" scope="user"` parameters (which essentially creates a cookie).

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset%7D#scope--user

Comment: I _do_ use Stash for some other things, but haven't delved deep into all its functionality. And Stash is potentially friendlier with caching plugins.